# Aligning nodes at the right periphery of the text area in forest

Tags: forest

I have to typeset trees with huge AVMs in them:

[image]

I want to do this with `forest` and the idea is to have all right nodes be aligned at the right periphery as it was done by hand in the picture above. Ideally this should be a specification at one node in the tree and it should affect everything below that node.

What I have is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=top}}}



\usepackage{array}


\makeatletter

\def\ibox#1{\mbox{}\setbox2=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\lower.2ex\vbox{\hrule
        \hbox{\vrule\kern1.25pt 
        \vbox{\kern1.25pt\box2\kern1.25pt}\kern1.25pt\vrule}\hrule}}


\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\upshape\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}

\newcommand{\liste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$%
\left\langle\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\upshape\scshape}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\rangle%
$%
%\\[-1.5mm]
}%
}


\newcommand{\phonliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$%
%
\left\langle \mbox{\normalfont\itshape#1} \right\rangle%
$%
%\\[-1.5mm]
}%
}


\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\def\ms{\futurelet\msLook\msdecide}
\def\msdecide{\ifx\msLook[\let\next=\xxtms%
\else\let\next=\xxms\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtms[#1]#2{%
\mbox{%
\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
#2%
\multicolumn{2}{>{\normalfont\itshape}l}{#1}%
\end{tabular}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}

\def\xxms#1{%
\mbox{%
\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
#1%
\end{tabular}%
\rule{0mm}{5mm}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}



\def\onems{\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt\futurelet\onemsLook\onemsdecide}
\def\onemsdecide{\ifx\onemsLook[\let\next=\xxtonems%
\else\let\next=\xxonems\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtonems[#1]#2{%
$\left[%
\begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
#2%
{\normalfont\itshape #1}% 
\end{tabular}% 
\right]$%
\vspace{1mm}%
}

\def\xxonems#1{%
\mbox{%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
#1%
\end{tabular}%
\rule{0mm}{5mm}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{forest}
    [
      \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        synsem \onems{ l \onems{ cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels \ibox{2} ] }\\[1mm]
                                 cont|rels \ibox{8} $\oplus$ \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
                                              arg & \ibox{5} \\
                            } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
                            }\\
                       is \ms{ topic & \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\
                               focus & \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
                             }\\
                     }\\
        c\_cont|hcons \liste{ \ms[qeq]{
                        harg & \ibox{5}\\
                        larg & \ibox{4}\\
                        } }\\
       }
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren }\\
        cat|head|dsl local \\
        cont|rels  \ibox{8}  \\
         } ]
      [   \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
                                 cont \ms{ ltop & \ibox{4}\\
                                           rels & \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
                                                                                                           arg & \ibox{5} \\
                                                                                                          } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}  \\
                                             }\\
        }
        [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist  }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels  \ibox{7}  \\
                               }
         ]
        [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels   \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
         }
          [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht }\\
        synsem \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels  \ibox{2} ] \\
          } ]
          [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
                       is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
            }
            [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht  }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
        } ]
            [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}\\
        } ] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}}


\end{document}
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]

**Edit**: Adding

```
, for tree={calign=last}
```

to the ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren-Node improves the space consumption, but the AVMs are centered then:

[image]

Comment: You don't want to use `avm` for drawing feature structures? Anyway, your example is larger than necessary to accompany your question, I think ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Vertical and Horizontal Alignment (Updated Question/Question in Comments)

In comments you asked how to combine an answer to the question here with an answer to your question about aligning the tops of nodes.

The following aligns nodes:

- vertically: at the top
- horizontally: at the right, except for the first level which is aligned, as before, with a phantom node between the two non-phantoms.

You could alternatively use a `midpoint` alignment option for the root node, to avoid the need for a phantom. But a phantom is quicker than looking up the right option for a one-off alignment.

The trick here is to align the rightmost nodes using `north east` anchors. However, we don't want to draw the tree this way because the lines will be in the wrong places.

So, after the positions of the nodes are set in stage `computing xy`, we alter the child and parent anchors to reset them to their default values prior to the final stage in which the tree is drawn.

The result:

[image: horizontal and vertical alignment]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\def\ibox#1{\mbox{}\setbox2=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\lower.2ex\vbox{\hrule
    \hbox{\vrule\kern1.25pt
      \vbox{\kern1.25pt\box2\kern1.25pt}\kern1.25pt\vrule}\hrule}}
\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $\left\langle\mbox{\upshape\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}
\newcommand{\liste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    \left\langle\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\upshape\scshape}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\rangle%
    $%
    %\\[-1.5mm]
  }%
}
\newcommand{\phonliste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    %
    \left\langle \mbox{\normalfont\itshape#1} \right\rangle%
    $%
    %\\[-1.5mm]
  }%
}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\def\ms{\futurelet\msLook\msdecide}
\def\msdecide{\ifx\msLook[\let\next=\xxtms%
  \else\let\next=\xxms\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtms[#1]#2{%
  \mbox{%
    \tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
      #2%
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\normalfont\itshape}l}{#1}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\xxms#1{%
  \mbox{%
    \tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
      #1%
    \end{tabular}%
    \rule{0mm}{5mm}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\onems{\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt\futurelet\onemsLook\onemsdecide}
\def\onemsdecide{\ifx\onemsLook[\let\next=\xxtonems%
  \else\let\next=\xxonems\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtonems[#1]#2{%
  $\left[%
  \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
    #2%
    {\normalfont\itshape #1}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \right]$%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\xxonems#1{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
      #1%
    \end{tabular}%
    \rule{0mm}{5mm}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={
        parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        anchor=north,
        align=center
      }
      [
      \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        synsem \onems{ l \onems{ cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels \ibox{2} ] }\\[1mm]
            cont|rels \ibox{8} $\oplus$ \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
                arg & \ibox{5} \\
              } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
          }\\
          is \ms{ topic & \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\
            focus & \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
          }\\
        }\\
        c\_cont|hcons \liste{ \ms[qeq]{
            harg & \ibox{5}\\
            larg & \ibox{4}\\
          } }\\
      },
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren }\\
        cat|head|dsl local \\
        cont|rels  \ibox{8}  \\
      },
      ]
      [, phantom, calign with current]
      [   \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont \ms{ ltop & \ibox{4}\\
          rels & \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
              arg & \ibox{5} \\
            } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}  \\
        }\\
      },
      parent anchor=east,
      anchor=north east,
      for descendants={
        where n'=1{
          calign with current,
          anchor=north east,
        }{},
      },
      before drawing tree={
        parent anchor=south,
        for descendants={
          if n'=1{
            child anchor=north,
            parent anchor=south,
          }{}
        }
      }
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist  }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels  \ibox{7}  \\
      },
      ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels   \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      },
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht }\\
        synsem \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels  \ibox{2} ] \\
      } ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      }
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht  }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      } ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}\\
      } ] ] ] ] ]
    \end{forest}}
\end{document}
```

## Horizontal Alignment Only (Original Question)

Like this?

[image: aligned]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, align=center,base=top}}}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter

\def\ibox#1{\mbox{}\setbox2=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\lower.2ex\vbox{\hrule
    \hbox{\vrule\kern1.25pt
      \vbox{\kern1.25pt\box2\kern1.25pt}\kern1.25pt\vrule}\hrule}}
\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $\left\langle\mbox{\upshape\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}
\newcommand{\liste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    \left\langle\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\upshape\scshape}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\rangle%
    $%
    %\\[-1.5mm]
  }%
}
\newcommand{\phonliste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    %
    \left\langle \mbox{\normalfont\itshape#1} \right\rangle%
    $%
    %\\[-1.5mm]
  }%
}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\def\ms{\futurelet\msLook\msdecide}
\def\msdecide{\ifx\msLook[\let\next=\xxtms%
  \else\let\next=\xxms\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtms[#1]#2{%
  \mbox{%
    \tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
      #2%
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\normalfont\itshape}l}{#1}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\xxms#1{%
  \mbox{%
    \tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
      #1%
    \end{tabular}%
    \rule{0mm}{5mm}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\onems{\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt\futurelet\onemsLook\onemsdecide}
\def\onemsdecide{\ifx\onemsLook[\let\next=\xxtonems%
  \else\let\next=\xxonems\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtonems[#1]#2{%
  $\left[%
  \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
    #2%
    {\normalfont\itshape #1}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \right]$%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\xxonems#1{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
      #1%
    \end{tabular}%
    \rule{0mm}{5mm}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{forest}
      [
      \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        synsem \onems{ l \onems{ cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels \ibox{2} ] }\\[1mm]
            cont|rels \ibox{8} $\oplus$ \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
                arg & \ibox{5} \\
              } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
          }\\
          is \ms{ topic & \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\
            focus & \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
          }\\
        }\\
        c\_cont|hcons \liste{ \ms[qeq]{
            harg & \ibox{5}\\
            larg & \ibox{4}\\
          } }\\
      },
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren }\\
        cat|head|dsl local \\
        cont|rels  \ibox{8}  \\
      },
      ]
      [, phantom, calign with current]
      [   \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont \ms{ ltop & \ibox{4}\\
          rels & \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
              arg & \ibox{5} \\
            } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}  \\
        }\\
      },
      before typesetting nodes={
        parent anchor=east,
        anchor=east,
        for descendants={
            where n'=1{
              child anchor=east,
              calign with current,
              anchor=east,
            }{},
        }
      },
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist  }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels  \ibox{7}  \\
      },
      ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels   \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      },
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht }\\
        synsem \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels  \ibox{2} ] \\
      } ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      }
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht  }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      } ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}\\
      } ] ] ] ] ]
    \end{forest}}
\end{document}
```

Or like this?

[image: semi-aligned]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, align=center,base=top}}}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter

\def\ibox#1{\mbox{}\setbox2=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\lower.2ex\vbox{\hrule
    \hbox{\vrule\kern1.25pt
      \vbox{\kern1.25pt\box2\kern1.25pt}\kern1.25pt\vrule}\hrule}}
\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $\left\langle\mbox{\upshape\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}
\newcommand{\liste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    \left\langle\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\upshape\scshape}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\rangle%
    $%
    %\\[-1.5mm]
  }%
}
\newcommand{\phonliste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    %
    \left\langle \mbox{\normalfont\itshape#1} \right\rangle%
    $%
    %\\[-1.5mm]
  }%
}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\def\ms{\futurelet\msLook\msdecide}
\def\msdecide{\ifx\msLook[\let\next=\xxtms%
  \else\let\next=\xxms\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtms[#1]#2{%
  \mbox{%
    \tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
      #2%
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\normalfont\itshape}l}{#1}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\xxms#1{%
  \mbox{%
    \tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
      #1%
    \end{tabular}%
    \rule{0mm}{5mm}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\onems{\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt\futurelet\onemsLook\onemsdecide}
\def\onemsdecide{\ifx\onemsLook[\let\next=\xxtonems%
  \else\let\next=\xxonems\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtonems[#1]#2{%
  $\left[%
  \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
    #2%
    {\normalfont\itshape #1}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \right]$%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\def\xxonems#1{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    \left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
      #1%
    \end{tabular}%
    \rule{0mm}{5mm}%
    \right]%
    $%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{forest}
      [
      \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        synsem \onems{ l \onems{ cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels \ibox{2} ] }\\[1mm]
            cont|rels \ibox{8} $\oplus$ \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
                arg & \ibox{5} \\
              } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
          }\\
          is \ms{ topic & \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\
            focus & \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
          }\\
        }\\
        c\_cont|hcons \liste{ \ms[qeq]{
            harg & \ibox{5}\\
            larg & \ibox{4}\\
          } }\\
      },
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren }\\
        cat|head|dsl local \\
        cont|rels  \ibox{8}  \\
      },
      ]
      [   \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont \ms{ ltop & \ibox{4}\\
          rels & \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
              arg & \ibox{5} \\
            } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}  \\
        }\\
      },
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist  }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels  \ibox{7}  \\
      },
      ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels   \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      },
      before typesetting nodes={
        parent anchor=east,
        anchor=east,
        for descendants={
            where n'=1{
              child anchor=east,
              calign with current,
              anchor=east,
            }{},
        }
      },
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht }\\
        synsem \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels  \ibox{2} ] \\
      } ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      }
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht  }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
      } ]
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}\\
      } ] ] ] ] ]
    \end{forest}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the first solution is the best in terms of space conservation. Thanks! However, all solutions seem to involve `anchor` and are incompatible to the solution to another problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255101/aligning-siblings-with-complex-content-in-forest/255156#255156 Are there ways to combine these solutions?

Comment: @StefanMüller `anchor=north east`?

Comment: @StefanMüller See updated answer. I think this is what you meant? I combined the horizontal alignment from the first tree I drew here originally with the vertical alignment from the tree in my answer to your other question. Let me know whether that's what you meant.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted. I do not understand it yet, but will think about it. The phantom node. Hm.

Comment: @StefanMüller It really just doing things at different stages. From the documentation, I think it should be possible to do this more straightforwardly because it should be possible to align on node anchors while drawing from parent to child anchors. However, I couldn't make this work.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `for tree={anchor=base east,calign=last}` to the second daughter of the second daughter (Gorn address 22). This at least works in some cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=top}}}



\usepackage{array}


\makeatletter

\def\ibox#1{\mbox{}\setbox2=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\lower.2ex\vbox{\hrule
        \hbox{\vrule\kern1.25pt 
        \vbox{\kern1.25pt\box2\kern1.25pt}\kern1.25pt\vrule}\hrule}}


\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\upshape\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}

\newcommand{\liste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$%
\left\langle\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\upshape\scshape}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\rangle%
$%
%\\[-1.5mm]
}%
}


\newcommand{\phonliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$%
%
\left\langle \mbox{\normalfont\itshape#1} \right\rangle%
$%
%\\[-1.5mm]
}%
}


\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\def\ms{\futurelet\msLook\msdecide}
\def\msdecide{\ifx\msLook[\let\next=\xxtms%
\else\let\next=\xxms\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtms[#1]#2{%
\mbox{%
\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
#2%
\multicolumn{2}{>{\normalfont\itshape}l}{#1}%
\end{tabular}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}

\def\xxms#1{%
\mbox{%
\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}%
#1%
\end{tabular}%
\rule{0mm}{5mm}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}



\def\onems{\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt\futurelet\onemsLook\onemsdecide}
\def\onemsdecide{\ifx\onemsLook[\let\next=\xxtonems%
\else\let\next=\xxonems\fi\next}
%
\def\xxtonems[#1]#2{%
$\left[%
\begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
#2%
{\normalfont\itshape #1}% 
\end{tabular}% 
\right]$%
\vspace{1mm}%
}

\def\xxonems#1{%
\mbox{%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}%
#1%
\end{tabular}%
\rule{0mm}{5mm}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{forest}
    [
      \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        synsem \onems{ l \onems{ cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels \ibox{2} ] }\\[1mm]
                                 cont|rels \ibox{8} $\oplus$ \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{
                                              arg & \ibox{5} \\
                            } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
                            }\\
                       is \ms{ topic & \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\
                               focus & \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
                             }\\
                     }\\
        c\_cont|hcons \liste{ \ms[qeq]{
                        harg & \ibox{5}\\
                        larg & \ibox{4}\\
                        } }\\
       }
      [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nach Brüssel zum Demonstrieren }\\
        cat|head|dsl local \\
        cont|rels  \ibox{8}  \\
         } ]
      [   \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
                                 cont \ms{ ltop & \ibox{4}\\
                                           rels & \ibox{7} $\oplus$ \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} \ms[nicht-rel]{                                                             } } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}  \\
                                             }\\
        }
        [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ ist  }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels  \ibox{7}  \\
                               }
         ]
        [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels   \ibox{2} $\oplus$ \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
         },for tree={anchor=base east,calign=last}
          [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ Gerd Knecht }\\
        synsem \ibox{1} [ l|cont|rels  \ibox{2} ] \\
          } ]
          [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht gefahren }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6} \\
                       is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
            }
            [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ nicht  }\\
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } \\
        is|focus \sliste{ \sliste{ \ibox{3} } }\\
        } ]
            [ \onems{
        phon \phonliste{ gefahren }\\
        cat|head|dt \sliste{ \ibox{1} }\\[1mm]
        cont|rels \liste{ \ibox{3} } $\oplus$ \ibox{6}\\
        } ] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}}


\end{document}
```

[image]